# Which entry in phpinfo() tells about the GD library?

Tags: php

I want to make a captcha programming inside my form. I googled about "php captcha" and I found that the GD library should be installed. I made a phpinfo() and I cannot see what is the keyword to recognize the GD library ; the version of my PHP is 5.2.1

So what is the entry text of the GD library in phpinfo() , and how to enable the GD library ?

Comment: See http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/gd-support.php a very quick search on the internets yielded loads of results for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go for **gd** section and check (if you have enabled you found a new section with named `gd`)

```
GD Support enabled
GD Version bundled
```

For more check :- http://www.zoopable.com/check-php-gd-library-installed-or-not/

For enable:-

`Windows` :-  uncomment the `extension=php_gd2.dll` line in your php.ini file

`Linux` :- yum install php-gd or apt-get install php5-gd

Be sure to restart your apache after installing the library.

For more read manual :- http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

Answer (score 2):

Please check out the following:
http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/gd-support.php

Answer (score 1):

There's usually a section titled "gd" and also a gd.ini in "Additional .ini files parsed"